# php function that takes as input the name of a excel file, and returns an array of associative arrays with the content of excel file

Tags: php, arrays, function, phpexcel, associative-array

I need a function that takes as input the name of a excel file, and returns an array of associative arrays with the content of excel file.

signature of the funtion like this

```
function getExcelData($excelfilepath) { 
    return $exceldata; 
}
```

In my case each element is a row of the excel file (the first line contains the name of the column

```
$exceldata[0] it's a row 2 
$exceldata[1] è la row 3 
... 
$exceldata[n] it's a row n-2
```

So in my case the array has 3 elements (the first is the name of the columns).
Each row, then each array element, is in turn an associative array that contains the row data:

```
$exceldata[0]["campo1"] contains 1 and $exceldata[2]["pippo"] contains 3
```

for do this i try use phpexcel and i write function like this

```
$inputFileName=$UploadDirectory . $FileName;
function getExcelData($inputFileName){
    $inputFileName=$UploadDirectory . $FileName;
    try {
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $phpExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
        $sheet = $phpExcel->getSheet(0);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $highestrow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestcolumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
    $columncount = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestcolumn);
    $titles = $sheet->rangeToArray('A1:' . $highestcolumn . "1");
    $body = $sheet->rangeToArray('A2:' . $highestcolumn . $highestrow);
    $table = array();
    for ($row = 0; $row <= $highestrow - 2; $row++) {
        $a = array();
        for ($column = 0; $column <= $columncount - 1; $column++) {
            $a[$titles[0][$column]] = $body[$row][$column];
        }
        $table[$row] = $a;
    }
    var_dump ($table);
    return $table;
}
```

but not work... please i need help!

Comment: What happens when you run this? Do you get any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be worth checking out Nuovo's Spreadsheet Reader Instead. It looks simple, and produces output as associative arrays of row data, like you're looking for.

https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader

Example usage snippet:

```
<?php
    // If you need to parse XLS files, include php-excel-reader
    require('php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');

    require('SpreadsheetReader.php');

    $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader('example.xlsx');
    foreach ($Reader as $Row)
    {
        print_r($Row);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious obvious problem:

```
function getExcelData($inputFileName){
    $inputFileName=$UploadDirectory . $FileName;
```

You're passing in the `$inputFileName` value but overwriting that with `$UploadDirectory . $FileName`, neither of which variables exists in the scope of your function; but as long as you do pass in the correct value for `$inputFileName`, then the function should work without problem

You could simplify it though:

```
function getExcelData($inputFileName){
    try {
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $phpExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
        $sheet = $phpExcel->getSheet(0);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }
    $highestrow = $sheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestcolumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
    $titles = $sheet->rangeToArray('A1:' . $highestcolumn . "1");
    $body = $sheet->rangeToArray('A2:' . $highestcolumn . $highestrow);

    array_walk($body, function (&$row) use($titles) { $row = array_combine($titles[0], $row); });

    return $body;
}
```